# Difference between 'in the whole of Europe' and 'in Europe as a whole'

Tags: expressions

What if I compare the two 'Germany' and 'Europe' in a paragraph but not in a sentence. I would like to write a sentece about Europe in that paragraph.

Should I write: "Nuclear energy was the main fuel for electricity **in the whole of Europe** " or "... **in Europe as a whole**" or simply "... **in Europe**"?"

In another question ([Expression 'Europe as a whole' or only 'Europe'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528312/expression-europe-as-a-whole-or-only-europe)) I was told to use 'Europe as a whole' if I compare Germany and Europe within one sentence. 
But what shall I do in this case?

Update: Hi, I just have a follow up question: Do I have to say '**In** Europe as a whole, nuclear energy was the main source...' or '**For** Europe as a whole, nuclear energy was the main source ...' I'd really appreciate any comment and your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulations are relatively imprecise, and could be interpreted in different ways, but *in the whole of Europe* would most likely be understood to mean throughout Europe. Using that wording in the OP's example would imply that nuclear energy was the main source of electricity in every, or almost every, region (part) of Europe. Using *in Europe as a whole*, on the other hand, would most likely be understood to mean that the largest percentage of Europe's total electricity production comes from nuclear energy, which is something different.

To see the difference, one should imagine a scenario in which a few countries, concentrated in one part of Europe, produce (and/or consume), say 70%, of the continent's total electricity, with 80% of it (i.e. 56% of the continent's total) coming from nuclear energy, while the many countries spread through the rest of the continent do not use nuclear energy at all. In that hypothetical case it would be true that nuclear energy is the main source of electricity in Europe as a whole, but false that it is its main source in the whole of Europe.

Incidentally it is somewhat awkward to say that nuclear energy was the main fuel for electricity; it would be better to say that it was its main source. *Fuel* normally stands for the stuff that embodies energy, rather than for energy itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot jsw29 for your answer. Basically what I want to say is, as you wrote in the end of your first paragraph "the largest percentage of Europe's total electricity production comes from nuclear energy". If I understood correctly, you would adivce me to use 'Eurpe as a whole' is this case. Further, do you think I can say "Nuclear energy was the main fuel for generating electricity"?

Comment: Any comments on my last post? Did I understand correctly that I should use 'Europe as a whole'? And can I use the term 'fuel for generating electrictiy'? I'd really appreciate every comment

Comment: @PeterBe, yes, if the point of the sentence concerns the percentage of the total production (and not its geographic distribution), then *Europe as a whole* is more apt. 'Nuclear energy was the main fuel' would be readily understood, but would be odd, because the word *fuel* normally stands for the stuff (petrol, coal, uranium, etc.) that embodies energy and is capable of releasing it in a way that suits human purposes, rather than for the energy itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jsw29. So you would say 'Nuclear energy ws the main source for electricity generation'?

Comment: Thanks for your answer jsw29. Is the term 'main source' better

Comment: Hi jsw29. I did some research and found out that quite many offical sites label nuclear energy as a fuel. For example the International Energy Agancy (https://www.iea.org/reports/monthly-oecd-electricity-statistics) or the European Environment agency (https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/indicators/electricity-production-by-fuel-1/electricity-production-by-fuel-assessment-3). What is your take on that? I think it is okay to use fuel, because they are also using it (and my statistics are based on their data)

Comment: @PeterBe, you may wish to supplement that research by checking a few reputable dictionaries and then form your own judgement.

Comment: Thanks jsw29 for your answer. What do you mean by 'supplement that research'. As said before, there are many political or scietific articles that label nuclear energy as a fuel